# VS 2008 installed on Win 8 over VS 2012 & Fail to open a Smart Project - MSBuildBinPath issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-cf-3.5

I had developed an app for Smart Project for WinCE using VS 2008 .NET3.5

Today on my Win 8 system, I have VS 2012. i installed VS 2008 Pro from : - 
Visual Studio 2008: (3,30 GB) http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/d/81d3f35e-fa03-485b-953b-ff952e402520/VS2008ProEdition90dayTrialENUX1435622.iso
I installed .NET Compact Framework 3.5 also

It got installed properly, running normally well. But, when I try to open my WinCE project or create new Smart Project for Win CE .NET 3.5, it gives this error :
[image: ERROR]

To open my exsting project, it shows error :
[image: ERROR - Open Existing project]

In C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5 & C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5 I can find file Microsoft.CSharp.targets **BUT NO** Microsoft.CompactFamework.CSharp.targets  . In the wholse system I cannot find this file at all.

The  statement in .csprj file is :

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets" />
```

Can anyone please help me figure out where I am going wrong. Why the system doesn't contain `Microsoft.CompactFamework.CSharp.targets` file which MSBuildBinPath is looking for ??? How to know the MSBuildinPAth ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Microsoft Power Toys fr .NET CF 3.5, restored/copied those files and am able to open the project. Link - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13442

Thanks.